# Question About Resigning Mid-Semester

Tags: job-search, quitting

I just accepted a non-academic job 10 days before the start of spring semester. It's too good to pass up - nearly double pay, remote, in my field, etc. - and they would like a start date in mid-February. I am currently a NTT teaching professor on a three-year rolling contract scheduled to teach three courses this semester (two different upper-division special topics courses and one freshman-level intro course).

The requested start date for the new position, which seems pretty set in stone, would mean I would need to leave my faculty position about five weeks into the semester. I would love to put in notice now and have some down time until February, but a) I can't afford to go without salary and my unused sick leave wouldn't make up for more than a month of salary and b) that's very little notice for my department to find replacement instructors for my courses. My current thinking is to put in notice next week for a termination date that coincides with or slightly overlaps with my start date with my new employer, which would give them more time to find replacement instructors. But the idea of teaching five weeks and then bailing seems less than desirable.

What other options might I consider? I do not want to burn bridges with my university (though I am more than happy to leave after years of being undervalued and poorly paid) but also need to make a sound financial decision. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Be prepared for your contract to be terminated immediately, with others taking over the teaching role (changing instructors mid-stream is not a good thing often).

Comment: Are you in the US? If they relieve you of your courses will you have access to unemployment insurance?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 6):

Talk to your department head immediately, as was the advice in your earlier question. Give them the maximum opportunity to do right by the students. Of course, consider also any contractual obligations you  might have.

The head might agree to have you start the course. They might have others who could either start it or take it up, such as an adjunct or an overload by another professor. Perhaps a discussion could find some other mutually acceptable solution.

But delaying that conversation would be unethical. In what might be the worst case you might need to depend on loans to cover a break. With nearly double pay in the new job that shouldn't be a big issue, as it is temporary.

If you haven't discussed a delayed start with the new employer, do so. Until you have a discussion there might be options you don't know of. This would be especially the case if you are highly desirable to the new place.

But, don't mislead the chair about things. It is unfair to both the institution and, more importantly, the students who might be affected. Do. The. Right. Thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you submit the letter to the chair ASAP with the effective date as the day before your start date. That is only fair, it gives them time do make a plan. Since you are full time and you are really only talking about a few weeks of pay, it will probably be better for them to just spend the money than to get lawyers involved. When I was a Dean I sometimes had to come up with special projects for people who were in weird situations to do for a few weeks.  That's what I would suggest, volunteer to tutor or to fully document your courses so others can use them or offer to mentor the new instructors.

Answer (score 2):

You are about to cause your chair the biggest headache imaginable. Consider every bridge burnt.

However, congrats on the new job. Do what's right for you AND accept the consequences. As an educator this really is an awful thing to do (especially for the students)... but again, if it's the right thing for you, do it and accept the fall out.

Comment: I am thinking why your start date for new job is set stone? If so, can they allow you to work before your set stone date so you can quit before semester starts and your department doesn’t need to adjust in the middle of semester? You know your future job better than me but will they be flexible enough in the future if they are not flexible enough now (or that’s not under consideration for you)?